# Is ext4 fast_commit really stable? (Linux 6.3)

Tags: filesystems, ext4, journaling

It seems I've been too quick to enable `fast_commit` on most my ext4 file systems and since then I often experienced FS corruptions. I've never ever had this kind of issues with ext4 that has been rock solid for me for years.

Nothing too bad as `e2fsck` has always been able to fix them without data loss but having an unbootable system gets old fast.

I've disabled `fast_commit` now with `tune2fs -O "^fast_commit" /dev/partitions` but I was wondering if there was something I missed when setting it up?

Is it a known problem and I should have tried changing the journaling order method for instance?
I haven't changed it so I guess they are still in the default `ordered` mode unless `fast_commit` changes that or makes it irrelevant?

Comment: `been too quick to enable fast_commit` not sure, is 2 years after it was introduced too quick?

Comment: I'm genuinely wondering. Still recovering from btrfs PTSD

Comment: I'd be surprised if something that's been around since Linux 5.18 (or even earlier, can't recall) is broken ... however, it may be broken in Linux 6.3 I guess - I'm not sure where one would even look for ext4 bugs

Comment: Yeah it's strange to me too, It's actually been mainlined as early as 5.10 so I don't know… but I've started having the same metadata corruptions on all my systems only days after enabling it on all my systems so I just guessed it was the culprit. It could be something else of course but it seemed too big of a coincidence.

I'm using LUKS on LVM and LVM on LUKS on those systems (as well as fscrypt) so I thought maybe it's a bad interactions between all of those.

Comment: After enabling it on Linux 6.7.6 I experienced many issues while gaming.

Answer (score 1):

Just to say "me too."  I put fast_commit on my systems, then removed it eventually due to having the systems fail to boot due to needing a manual fsck.

I *think* what is happening is fsck sees some inconsistency that is entirely normal if fast_commit didn't get a chance to, well, commit it's stuff to the filesystem (power outage, crash, my dad deciding he'll just shut off his desktop by holding down the power button, etc.)  So fsck can reliably fix this and it's not a problem, but fsck is not updated yet to recognize this scenario and realize this is a normal situation so it goes to the "run fsck by hand and manually OK it" situation.

When fast_commit came out I looked at it's design and it's pretty conservative -- it writes these commits into a new journal first, then writes them out to the filesystem at it's convenience.  So the worst case should be losing the last few seconds of filesystem changes, not having the filesystem totally blow out and lose your data.